# Is there a way to use JS event listeners to run on scroll every time so that the code runs and acts appropriately based upon the conditions?

Tags: javascript, scroll, facebook-javascript-sdk, addeventlistener, facebook-messenger

I am working on a website where I have a hero image that goes all of the way to the fold of the browser. I embedded the Facebook Customer Chat/Messenger widget. I do not want it to load on top of the hero image. So what I have done is set an if statement so that the widget will not load until the visitor scrolls past the hero and then it will disappear if the visitor scrolls back up to the hero image. What I cannot figure out is how to make the widget reappear when it scrolls back down beyond the hero. I believe that event listeners are the correct way to do this but I am clearly missing something. I have tried this about three different ways. All three ways accomplish the goal of (1) not loading the widget on the hero image, (2) loading the widget after scrolling beyond the hero/fold and (3) hiding the widget when the visitor scrolls back up to the hero image. Neither accomplishes the goal of (4) revealing the widget again once the user scrolls back beyond the hero.

These are the most promising ways that have tried that have met 3/4 objectives. Adding the else at the end of the statement broke the code in each case.

**ONE ATTEMPT**

```
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
<div id='fb-root'></div>
<script>
window.onscroll = function() {showMessenger()};

function showMessenger() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 400 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 400) {
    (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12&autoLogAppEvents=1';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  } else if (document.body.scrollTop < 400 || document.documentElement.scrollTop < 400){
  FB.CustomerChat.hide();
  }
}
</script>

      <!-- Your customer chat code -->
  <div class='fb-customerchat'
    attribution="wordpress"
    page_id='FACEBOOKPGID'
    theme_color='#000000'
    logged_in_greeting='Hey! How can I help?'
    logged_out_greeting='Hey! How can I help?'
  >
</div>
```

**
ANOTHER ATTEMPT
**

```
<div id='fb-root'></div>
<script>
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if(window.scrollY > 399) {
        (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12&autoLogAppEvents=1';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
      } else {
      FB.CustomerChat.hide();
      }
});
</script>
  <div class='fb-customerchat'
    attribution="wordpress"
    page_id='___'
    theme_color='#000000'
    logged_in_greeting='Hey! How can I help?'
    logged_out_greeting='Hey! How can I help?'
  >
</div>
```

**
ORIGINAL FB EMBED CODE
**

```
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            xfbml            : true,
            version          : 'v5.0'
          });
        };

        (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

      <!-- Your customer chat code -->
      <div class="fb-customerchat"
        attribution=setup_tool
        page_id="___"
  theme_color="#000000"
  logged_in_greeting="Hey! If there is anything I can help you with let me know."
  logged_out_greeting="Hey! If there is anything I can help you with let me know.">
      </div>
```

Comment: Use FB original code, then, add a listener for scrolling and just show or hide chat box when needed. Because right now you're trying to hide an unexistent element (else) and try to create new chat box (if).

Comment: @Triby Thanks for the feedback. I am using an event listener in the second attempt. Am I not using it appropriately?

Comment: @InnovativeTechnologyConcepts, no, leave the FB original code outside the listener.